# Swing: how can I ignore deselection events?

Tags: java, swing, selection, listener, jtree

My custom component is composed of three `JTree`s inside a `JPanel`. Only one `JTree` should be selected at a time, so I've added a `TreeSelectionListener` to each of them that calls `clearSelection()` on the previously selected `JTree`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460468/swing-listeners-execution-order-on-custom-component) for more details).

That works fine, but I need to prevent the `TreeSelectionListener`s to trigger when a `JTree` is *deselected*. A simple way to distinguish a selection event from a deselection one would be more than enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the current selection from the tree and if it's empty, return.

Comment: Just as simple as "if (selectedTree.getSelectionCount() != 0)". I must admit I feel a little bit stupid :D Thanks!